# Browser hijack protection for Firefox (BrowserProtect is dead)

Tags: security, firefox, malware

I installed K-Lite Codec pack and it installed Bing(R) as a search provider and reset my homepage to Bing (in Firefox, but not PaleMoon).  I don't like or use Bing.  While this isn't the most nefarious example, it reminded me that this is still a thing.

Looking for a shield or poison, I came across several recommendations for [BrowserProtect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/browserprotect/) ([sevenforums](https://www.sevenforums.com/browsers-mail/265410-protect-my-browser-home-page-please.html), [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/480410/288928)).  Running it through a search, I see many things calling or implying that BrowserProtect is some kind of malware.  Also, the extension was removed by its author.

Is there a comparable extension or other software that can fulfill this same goal?

Requirements

- Free or 1 time fee
- Runs on Windows

Bonus points

- Runs on Firefox Android
- FOSS

Comment: If you run a program, and it has the permissions it needs to reconfigure Firefox (which should usually be the case—you don't need administrator privileges to set your homepage), it can do what it wants. I don't know how a Firefox extension could help with this.

Comment: The same way anti-malware software fends off malware: by monitoring something and preventing known or heuristically-suspect software from making changes to that something.